# Index page doesn't recognize method that has already been defined in the model (rails 4.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, video, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been stuck on this for days. In the model, i've defined 'code' which formats a youtube link to be added in an iframe. When i go to localhost:3000/videos , it gives me this

"undefined method `code' for #"

```
<h1>Video Index</h1>
<% @videos.each do |video| %>
    <div class="table-bordered">
    <iframe width="560" height="349" src="<%= "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+@videos.code %>"></iframe>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Now when if I jump to the show page (localhost:3000/videos/#) it works fine. Here's the show.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
            <ol class="video">
                <iframe width="560" height="349" src="<%= "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+@video.code %>"></iframe>
            </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't see the problem with the index in my controller either. @videos = Video.all seems pretty straight forward.

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @videos = Video.all
    end

    def show
        @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    end
```

This the model. video.rb where I have defined code

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
    belongs_to :user
    default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
    validates :video, presence: true, length: { maximum: 420 }

    def code
      self.video.try(:split, '/').try(:last) || ''
    end
end
```

Here is the user, which is who the videos belong to

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos
```

Thanks for the help for whoever responds, and be sure to give me a rep point so i can be at 15 and rep you back ;)

Comment: apologies, this is the whole error "undefined method `code' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Video:0x007fa16dc456b0>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@videos` should not have such method `code` which should be an instance method.

You need to use `video` instead of `@videos` inside the loop.

Besides, the view code looks PHPish. It needs improvement.

#### Refactor

Instead of

```
<iframe width="560" height="349" src="<%= "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+@videos.code %>">
</iframe>
```

Try this

```
# View
video_iframe video.code

# Helper
def video_iframe(src)
  content_tag(:iframe, width: 500, height: 349, src: src)
end

# Model
def code
  if process_video.present?
    "http://www.youtube.com/embed/#{process_video}"
  end
end

private
def process_video
  video.try(:split, '/').try(:last) || ''
end
```